# How to disable navagation on the URL Bar

Tags: android, html, ios, css, internet-explorer

How do I make it so when a user clicks on my website button, it doesn't add on the the URL bar, for example, when they click on a button it will open a modal box, example.com/index.html#modalopened but I don't want that to show, I want it to only say example.com/index.html instead of the # stuff....

I tried onClick="return false;" but it made it so the button didn't work at all... :(

Any other suggestions?

Also, maybe its just easyer to disable it totally, so that when people visit the site it just says example.com instead of example.com/index.html :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular.js to dynamically update page content without changing the URL. https://angularjs.org/
Also by using a .htaccess (depending on what webserver you're using) you can get rid of the /index.html, too and have something like http://example.com/

Comment: Isnt there an easyer way? like just something to pop in like the onclick="return false;" thing?

Comment: WOW THANKS FOR THE HELP!